# Apache Spark performance tuning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am facing a performance issue while loading a 4MB file to hive table with Upsert (Insert & Update records) logic. As part of this load, we have two stages -

Stage 1 - loading a 4MB text file to table A

Stage 2 - loading table B by excluding source_code NOT IN ("ABC") from table A which returns around 6 million records

```
val finalizedDf= sparkSession.sql(s"""select * from $tableA where $source_code not in ("ABC")""")


finalizedDf.write.format("parquet").mode("Overwrite").insertInto(tableB)
```

While inserting to table B, the job fails due to memory limit exceeding executor memoryoverhead. Also, the load runs for more than 5 hours. Please recommend performance turning tips for the above situation :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to be considered while performing performance tuning in spark.

1. What is the shuffle partition set? By default, it is set to 200. You need to change that to some bigger number. `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1000`
2. Executor cores & Executor memory. By looking at the description, it seems to me the executor memory is less. Less memory will trigger GC frequently slowing down spark execution. Try to increase it.
3. You don't need the `overwrite` while performing insertInto.

Use this instead.
 `finalizedDf.write.format("parquet")
        .insertInto(tableB)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Avishek ! Table B requires an Insert overwrite everytime. That's the reason we have mode(overwrite). I am thinking since the table A is hit every time and checked for source_code, the load is running for 5 hours.

Comment: You might try to save the intermediate data after excluding the source_code and use that for the insertInto.